# Are there differences between $\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : -7 \leq n \lt 6 \} \text{ and } \{ n : n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } -7 \leq n \lt 6\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can’t tell if it makes a difference to write $n \in \mathbb{N}$ on the elements side or conditions side of set builder notation. Supposedly

$$\{n \in \mathbb{N} : -7 \leq n \lt 6 \} = \{ -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$$

But I can’t quite wrap my head around why that is. I would have figured the set to be equivalent to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, but I suspect my understanding of notation is to blame.

Comment: $\Bbb{N}$ denotes the set of natural numbers, is $-2$ a natural number? Try to read what the notations mean, $n \in \Bbb{N}$ means $n$ is a natural number.' : ' reads as 'such that', then there is the condition $-7 \leq n <6$, so altogether it reads as $n$ is a natural number such that $n$ is greater or equal to $-7$ and $n$ is less than $6$

Comment: The two notations in your title denote the same set. The first one is more usual. This set is $\{1,2,3,4,5\},$ as explained in the previous comment.

Comment: Only a notational variant; in general, $\{ x \in A \mid P(x) \} = \{ x \mid x \in A \text { and } P(x) \}$.